# Command re-execution for a simple shell

Tags: c, shell, unix

I've managed to get halfway through an assignment which asks that I implement a history function in a simple shell (in C, using a UNIX box remotely through PuTTY). It essentially mimics the csh history functions. It saves past commands from the command line in a file that formats like this, for example:

1 - pwd

2 - echo hello

3 - whoami

The problem I have now is how to get it to re-execute commands. For example, the input "!3" executes whoami again. And the input "!echo" re-executes the last command starting with that string, "echo hello".

The professor said this should be done using string comparison. He said it should not be extremely complex. I have managed to make "!!" print the last command, as well. But the other two re-executions, I do not know what technique to use. To print history, I am just comparing the input with the string "history" and for "!!" I was comparing that to the input stream as well. But for these I don't know how to check and compare the input. Is strcmp possible to use for this or am I looking in the wrong direction?

At the risk of sounding stupid, I should note I am still very new to programming, particularly in C, and this class has not provided a whole lot of guidance.

Comment: You should use strncmp.

Comment: How would you compare something like this? Since the number or string the follows the "!" will always be different, you can't compare it directly.

Comment: Compare it to each of the things you have to compare it to.

Comment: See if user input starts with `'!'`, then if it it does, handle *rest of that line* separately. Use a `strtol` call to both detect if there is a number at some position in a string, and parse it if there is. On another note, this question is quite broad and not a good fit for SO, it would need to show your current code and explain what is the problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a number (hint: read about [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)) then check the numbers.

If it's not a number, then search for the command.

Internally, you can store it as a linked list, where each node contains the number and the command.

Comment: How do I check if the input contains !(number) or !(string)? My comparison checks for the word "history" and "!!" correctly but for a non-constant coming from the input, I don't really know how checking that for a specific format like "!4" would work. I'm not even sure how csh does it.

Comment: @user3407266 Read the linked reference in my hint. And experiment with pointer arithmetic (for example, if you have `char str[] = "!4";`, print out `str + 1`).